# Mapping nested objects from firebase document in flutter using fromMap

Tags: json, firebase, flutter, dart, factory

Good evening, I need some help in flutter when it comes to mapping nested objects.

Here I am getting a "Salon" document from firebase and I am mapping the data to it, knowing that the Agents data are "firebase references"  to the Agents collection ex: /agents/id [you can check the image below], so basically what I'm doing is getting the reference then calling a custom getData() that maps on its turn agents data to an Agent instance and returns it as an item of a list of Agents.

So what I want is mapping the future List<Future < < Agent > > that results to the List < Agent > agents

[firebase model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKsSm.png)

Here is what've done so far

```
class Salon {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String email;
  final String image;
  final String website;
  final String phoneNumber;
  
  final List<Agent> agents;
 



  Salon({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.email,
    this.image,
    this.website,
    this.phoneNumber,
    this.agents,
  
  });

  factory Salon.fromMap(Map data) {
    return Salon(
      id: data['id'] ?? '',
      name: data['name'] ?? '',
      website: data['website'] ?? '',
      email: data['email'] ?? '',
      image: data['image'] ?? 'default.png',
      phoneNumber: data['phoneNumber'] ?? '',
  
      agents: (data['agents'] as List ?? []).map((item) async {
        Document<Agent> agentRef = item;
        Agent agent = await agentRef.getData();
        return agent;
      }).toList(),
    
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write `fromMap` and `toMap` by yourself. The flutter community already cared about it.
Just use [JsonSerializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) package to automate this process. It already works with nested objects.
What you need is make a request and then use something like that:

```
final data = await agentRef.getData();

final salon = Salon.fromJson(data);
```